# Laravel: Route to different code base

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I need to route to a different codebase based on logged in User's Company. Please do let me know can this be done. If so, please do let me know how to do it. The URL for both the users should be identical. That is, example.com/home should serve from different codebases based on user's company.

Comment: What do you mean with codebases?

Comment: a different Laravel application installation. My requirement is that some of the users need to be served with different functionality. Request should route to the same controller. Though the controller name is same, their internals will be different for two users. Therefore, I need to have two Laravel installations to cater for 2 different users.

Comment: Why cant you offer the same two different functions using the same laravel installation?

Comment: What if I have 100 users who will need different set of functionality.

Comment: you should elaborate more of what you are trying to do. so we can give you some suggestions.

Comment: Let's say I have a Web app and it serves two companies(A &  B). One of the companies (A) requested a modification to be done. When an employee of company A logs in, he should be served from the modified code. Please apply this scenario for example,  50 different companies having different modifications.

Comment: I think that using multiple installation is a crap. Use a factory, instead.

Comment: @Simone Could you please explain a little bit about factory thing?